# How to separate ID number from Row A to Row B?

Tags: atom-editor

So basically im stuck as I tried this code but it isn't splitting the names and number. PLs refer to the sample image to understand the desired outcome.

Code that i have tried

Comment: Please copy paste the full code. [Also Visit Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with quoting and separator. To clean your dataframe, use the code below:

```
pd.read_csv('names_tab2.csv', quoting=1, header=None)[0] \
  .str.split('\t', expand=True) \
  .to_csv('clean_names.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

---

**Old answer**
Use `str.extract`:

Suppose this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['CAIN TAN86092142', 'YEO KIAT JUN81901613']})
print(df)

# Output:
                   ColA
0      CAIN TAN86092142
1  YEO KIAT JUN81901613
```

Split on the first encountered digit:

```
out = df['ColA'].str.extract(r'([^\d]*)(\d+)') \
                .rename(columns={0: 'Name', 1: 'Number'})
print(out)

# Output:
           Name    Number
0      CAIN TAN  86092142
1  YEO KIAT JUN  81901613
```

**Update**:

> Is there a way to remove the Name and Number when it outputs to the csv?

```
out.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, header=None)

# content of data.csv:
CAIN TAN,86092142
YEO KIAT JUN,81901613
```

Comment: @codingn00b. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: yea kind of but is there a way to remove the Name and Number when it outputs to the csv?

Comment: hi sorry, how do u use the %cat function

Comment: It's not a Python command. Sorry, I removed it.

Comment: oh i see np :D . 1 more question. Is there a way to directly read from the file instead of manually inputting the data frame. Or do i have to copy and paste the data from notepad and set that as the data frame. Thanks

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv`. Open your file with Notepad, copy the first five lines of `'names_tab2.csv'` (the first line is the most important) and paste them in your post. I will update my answer with the right parameters of `read_csv`.

Comment: @codingn00b. I really don't understand the format of your file. Can you share it with `wetransfer` or another solution, please?

Comment: Now I understood the problem. See my update answer to clean your dataframe.

Comment: @Corralien Hi im trying to understand what the backslash ( \ )  and [0] and quoting = 1 means in your code. The result is correct but im just trying to understand what those objects mean. Thanks

Comment: `backslash` is to indicate to Python that the statement continue on the next line (line break). It's just for formatting on StackOverflow to avoid the ugly horizontal slider. `[0]` is the name of first column (automatically generated) because your csv file does not contain header. `quoting=1` is to indicate to Pandas all fields are quoted (`csv.QUOTE_ALL`). Does it clear for you now?

Comment: one more question @Corralien when u do the .str.split() and .to_csv() 
Is this a shortcut to a method?

Comment: All operations are chained. An operation like `.str.split(...)` return a modified copy of a dataframe so you can use another dataframe method and so on. Read this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unreasonable-effectiveness-of-method-chaining-in-pandas-15c2109e3c69)

Comment: i see, i posted a new question would be great if u could help :D @Corralien
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650287/how-to-find-duplicated-rows-of-data-in-csv-via-python-and-output-to-a-new-csv

Answer (score 0):

When opening a plain text file (or in this case a plain text csv file) you can use a for loop to go through the file line by line like so (Current as of Python 3):

```
name = []
id_num = []

file = open('file.csv', 'r')

for f in file:
    f = f.split(',')               # split the data
    name.append(str(f[0]))     # append name to list
    id_num.append(str(f[1]))   # append ID to list
```

Now that you have the data in lists, you can print/store it how you want.