# how to find duplicated rows of data and output

Tags: atom-editor

Currently finding the duplicates but the data is not showing the row number, name and number and isn't outputting correctly (See below for expected output).

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.duplicated` with `keep=False` to get a boolean mask of your dup rows then extract rows:

```
# split name / number from your csv file
df = pd.read_csv('names_dup2.csv', quoting=1, header=None)[0] \
       .str.split('\t', expand=True)

# increment index to match line number
df.index += 1

# keep duplicate entries
out = df[df[0].duplicated(keep=False)]

# export to duplicated_data.csv
out.to_csv('duplicated_data.csv', header=False)
```

Content of output file:

```
15,ANDREW ZHAO CHONG,83091746
19,ANDREW ZHAO CHONG,83091746
26,ANDREW ZHAO CHONG,83091746
48,ANDREW ZHAO CHONG,83091746
53,KOH KANG RI,89943392
56,KOH KANG RI,89943392
63,ENOS ZHAO KANG SONG,80746554
66,ENOS ZHAO KANG SONG,80746554
80,ENOS ZHAO KANG SONG,80746554
```

**One line version**

```
pd.read_csv('names_dup2.csv', quoting=1, header=None)[0] \
  .str.split('\t', expand=True) \
  .assign(index=lambda x: x.index+1) \
  .set_index('index') \
  [lambda x: x[0].duplicated(keep=False)] \
  .to_csv('duplicated_data.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: I tried using the code but  i dont know why its invalid syntax
df[df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False)]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: my names_dup2 still doesnt need headings

Comment: is there also a way to split it like in the pic above? the  .str.split() gives an unexpected indent error.
and the file is suppose to be names_dup.csv 
sample was just the expected output format

Comment: sorry i edited my post

Comment: @codingn00b. Now, I think I have what you expect (I hope) :)

Comment: yep :D its what i wanted, btw do u use visual studio, atom or something else as an IDE? Thanks again @Corralien

Comment: I used essentially Atom or PyCharm for large projects. Thanks again for your support :)

Comment: i see, no problem, are u a full time developer u seem really well versed in python :D

Comment: I'm not really a full time developer but I have to use Python/Pandas everyday.

Comment: I have a question , what does index = lambda x mean in the 1 line version?

Comment: I also posted a new question , would appreciate if u could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684924/how-to-compare-difference-in-2-txt-files-and-output-to-a-new-txt-file-and-print
@Corralien

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because [.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) returns a boolean series (True/False), which you are saving directly.

But you should be using this to subset the data, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


df_state = pd.DataFrame(
                [["3 Liu Yu,876"],
                ["4 Koh chong,123"],
                ["3 Liu Yu,876"]])

df_state = df_state[0].str.split(" ", expand= True)
print(df_state, "\n")

duplicated = df_state.duplicated() # just a boolean series
print(duplicated, "\n")

print(df_state[duplicated], "\n")  ## <- subset and save with .to_csv

# as Anders Källmar points out, you can also do this:

all_duplicated = df_state.duplicated(keep= False)
print(df_state[all_duplicated])
```

Output:

```
   0    1          2
0  3  Liu     Yu,876
1  4  Koh  chong,123
2  3  Liu     Yu,876 

0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool 

   0    1       2
2  3  Liu  Yu,876 

   0    1       2
0  3  Liu  Yu,876
2  3  Liu  Yu,876
```

Comment: Use the `keep` parameter to determine which to mark as duplicated. If you want to subset all duplicates use `keep=False`.

Comment: i got an invalid syntax when running it, is there a reason why?
df = df[0].str.split('\t', expand=True) \
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: pls see my updated post