# how to compare difference in 2 txt files and output to a new txt file

Tags: atom-editor

How to compare difference in 2 txt files and output and print it to shell?

working files in this link

Comment: The obvious answer is to forget about writing any code and use one of the dozens of tools that do this task: `diff`, `meld`, `vimdiff`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` with Pandas:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('members_1.txt', header=None).drop_duplicates()
df2 = pd.read_csv('members_2.txt', header=None).drop_duplicates()
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Output

```
>> print(*out[0].to_list(), sep='\n')
LEE RI KE
LIM YONG
KOH CHEE KIAT
LEE YONG
KOH CHEW KIAT
LEE RI KHEE
```

**OR**

Use `set` in Python:

```
with open('members_1.txt') as fp1, open('members_2.txt') as fp2:
    data1 = set([l.strip() for l in fp1])
    data2 = set([l.strip() for l in fp2])
    out = data1.symmetric_difference(data2)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(*out, sep='\n')
KOH CHEW KIAT
LEE RI KE
LEE YONG
KOH CHEE KIAT
LEE RI KHEE
LIM YONG
```

**Update**: export to file

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp:
    print(*out, sep='\n', file=fp)
```

Comment: I tried to use output.savetxt() but it doesnt work, is my syntax correct? @Corralien

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it what you expect?

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: malformed \N character escape, 
i got that  error, must i create the file first?

Comment: Why '\N' and not '\n'?

Comment: my bad wrong directory...

Comment: i realised *out[0].to_list() is still needed as without the .tolist() it returns a value of 0. Any idea why? i tought if its alr a list format  @Corralien

Comment: 0 is not a simple value, it's the column name. That's why I always use column names to avoid confusion :) Honestly, use the second version without Pandas for this task. You don't need it.

Comment: I see, understood :D

Answer (score 0):

of course use `diff`

[difflib.Differ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ)